Mobile offline capability for Custom app using mobile app plus license
Our team is considering offline capability for our custom lead, account generation app.
This app consist of search look ups which are using imperative apex calls to look up a custom lead object to find the  entered customer name and displays the account details of the selected lead.(This is the first page and in the next page the app creates certain custom object records and tasks based on selected checkbox fields ).
We went through mobile offline documentation and could see that it  prefers to have quick actions for viewing and editing the offline data either as a global action or record level action. But our team is keen on implementing the same existing UI in mobile offline too.
We have couple of questions here

List item

Is it possible for us to replicate the existing custom app UI with search looks ups as the landing page in offline app too..? From the mobile offline examples, We have seen that the landing page with briefcased objects and record or global level quick actions to view/edit records. And there is a default search option when you go to each offline object. Not sure if this is the only possible approach get records offline..?

List item

Is configuring landing page necessary step for offline apps..?

List item

Having quick action for view/edit record mandatory in the offline app..?
we are trying to understand that where restructuring of existing app is needed or not when going offline.
please share your thoughts and it will be a great start for us to further research on the capability
